# Work around for writing Destination argument as a script block in powershell

Tags: powershell, concatenation, filepath

My organization has a lot of picture files in different folders all over the network. 
I've been tying to consolidate them in a "PictureLibrary" folder by the project folder they're in.
Since there are other files besides picture files in these project folders I can't just move the whole folder.
I've been trying the code below:

```
    ($Images = gci "Z:\DivisionFolder" -Recurse -file -Include "*.jpg") |
        Foreach-object {
        copy-Item $_.DirectoryName -Destination "Z:\DivisionFolder\PictureLibrary"
        }
$a=0
For ($a; $a -lt $Images.count; $a++){
    move-item $Images[$a].fullname -Destination {join-path -Path "D:\(1) PROJECTS & PORTFOLIOS\PictureLibrary" -ChildPath $Images[$a].Directoryname}
    }
```

I've tried it in various formats but get this error

> Copy-Item : Cannot evaluate parameter 'Destination' because its
>   argument is  specified as a script block and there is no input. A
>   script block cannot be  evaluated without input.

and I can't figure out how to write this without writing destination as a Script block

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: Have you tried to use round brackets for the Join-Path insteas of curly brackets, that were the script block error is being thrown from.  -Destination (join-path ... Directoryname)

Comment: @ShamusBerube I did, it didn't give me the same error but unfortunately it still did not work.

Comment: Scriptblock parameters can only be used in a pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
($RougePictures = Get-Childitem -Path "C:\" -recurse -file -Include "*.JPG")|
   Foreach-object {
        copy-Item $_.DirectoryName -Destination "C:\Folders\PictureLibrary"
    }
$MainFolders = get-childitem -Path "D:\(1) PROJECTS & PORTFOLIOS\PictureLibrary"       

$a=0
For ($a; $a -lt $MainFolders.count; $a++) {
    Foreach ($Rouge in $RougePictures){
        if ((compare-object (split-path $Rouge.directoryname -leaf) $MainFolders[$a] -IncludeEqual).sideindicator -eq '=='){
             move-item $Rouge.fullname -destination $MainFolders[$a].fullname 
         }
    }
}
```

Found a work around for using a Script block as the destination argument. 
Used 
`if ((compare-object (split-path $Rouge.directoryname -leaf) $MainFolders[$a] -IncludeEqual).sideindicator -eq '==')`

after I copied the folders `copy-Item $_.DirectoryName -Destination "C:\Folders\PictureLibrary"` to find those that matched the folders the pictures are in. If it finds a match `'=='` the `move-item` moves those files.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the destination argument like this:

```
-Destination $(. { script_block_body_here })
```

() . { } is Dot sourcing operator and $( ) is Subexpression operator.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Not sure I'm formating it correctly, I looked up the `Get-Help 'about_Operators'` and from what I can understand came away with `-Destination $(. .\MovePics.ps1 {join-path -Path "D:\(1) PROJECTS & PORTFOLIOS\PictureLibrary" -ChildPath $Images[$a].Directoryname})` It copies the folders (`The $_.DirectoryName`) like before but gets stuck in a loop and never moves on to the `move-item`. Any suggestions?